# Find the AVERAGE of Multiple Dollar Amounts in Row, Skipping Blank Cells, with an ArrayFormula (or similar) in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, average, array-formulas, currency

I don't know why I'm having so much trouble with this, but I basically need a version of this...

```
=AVERAGE(A2:L2)
```

...But to put into something like an ArrayFormula in the header row so it will populate the average for each Row A:L, and place that average in Column M. For example...

- M2 should give the average of all the $ dollar price currency values in Row A2:L2.
- M3 should give the average of all the $ dollar price currency values in Row A3:L3.
- Etc.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like I can just pop "AVERAGE" into an ArrayFormula. Also, I need it to skip blank cells when determining the AVERAGE. Here's a demo of what I'm hoping for... (For reference, "Jan" is A1, "*Ave." is M1.)

| Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec | *Ave. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $2.00 | $4.00 |  | $8.00 | $6.00 | $4.00 |  | $8.00 | $10.00 |  |  |  | **$6.00** |
| $6.00 | $10.00 | $10.00 | $6.00 | $4.00 | $2.00 |  |  | $6.00 |  | $4.00 | $8.00 | **$6.22** |

*I'm hoping to place the formula in the cell M1 ("*Ave.") to produce the results for each row to be placed in that column.

I hope that all makes sense. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=vstack(
       "*Ave.",
       byrow(A2:L,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,average(Σ))))
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

Google sheets `AVERAGE()` ignores blank values. So

```
=BYROW(A2:L3,LAMBDA(i,AVERAGE(i)))
```

does what you need.

Comment: Thank you. This solution works as well, unless there are no entries and all cells are blank. In those cases, it returns an error. But that's rarely the case.

Comment: For that you can just use an IFERROR wrapper:

`=IFERROR(BYROW(A2:L3,LAMBDA(i,AVERAGE(i))),"Add an entry first!")`

Comment: Or it you want to stay within LABMDA logic, add a conditional evaluation inside and check every row for being not empty:

`=BYROW(A2:L3,LAMBDA(i,IF(COUNT(i)>0,AVERAGE(i),"Entry count is 0")))`